# validating poisson GAM models with caret

Tags: r, r-caret, gam, mgcv

I'm trying to run a cross-validation for a generalized additive model (GAM) using the 'caret' package in R. I can get this to work for a GLM, and think it should be simple to run the same thing for a GAM, but cannot get it to work, see below:

```
dat <- data.frame(label=round(rpois(100,20)),v1=rnorm(100),v2=rnorm(100))
tc <- trainControl("cv",10,savePred=T)
(fit <- train(label~.,data=dat,method="glm",trControl=tc,family=poisson(link = "log")))

(fit1 <- train(label~.,data=dat,method="gam",trControl=tc,family=poisson(link = "log")))
```

The crucial warning that is thrown when running the last line is this:

```
20: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  model fit failed for Fold10: select=FALSE, method=GCV.Cp Error in mgcv:::gam(modForm, data = dat, family = dist, select = param$select,  : 
  formal argument "family" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

It appears that somehow the family argument is not being passed to gam() in the same way that it is in glm(). I haven't found any working examples of this after searching the web exhaustively. Any help would be appreciated!

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further review, it appears that Poisson outcomes are explicitly not supported using any of the GAM-based model types in caret. I [flagged this as an issue](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/128) (in documentation at least, if not in explicit support of these types of models) in the caret codebase on Github.

Comment: This feature is checked-in and will be in the next CRAN version

Comment: @Nicolas: Since topepo (presumably the package author) did not choose to post this as answer here but rather answered it at the page you cited, I would suggest applying the checkmark to your feature_request-answer. (I just tested your example with a current version of caret and it runs without difficulty.)