# How to use tensor function of gam model in train function of caret package in r?

Tags: r, caret, gam, mgcv

I am using gam method with both spline and tensor interaction functions(s and ti) inside the train function (for test and train).
I know for spline functions in gam we can use method = "gam" in train function. for example:

```
fit <- gam(Y ~ s(x1)  + s(x2) + s(x3) , data=df)   
Prediction_gam <- as.numeric(predict(fit , data=df , type = "response"))
```

can be changed to follow for test and train in caret package:

```
fit_train <-  train(Y ~ x1  + x2 + x3 , data = train_df, method = "gam", trControl = train.control)
```

but I don't know how to add tensor interaction function of gam in train function for example:

```
fit <- gam(Y ~ s(x1)  + s(x2) + s(x3) + ti(x1,x2) , data=df)
```

any suggestion would be appreciated.
the full codes are as follow:

```
library(caret)
df <- data.frame(Y=rnorm(100), x1=rnorm(100),x2=rnorm(100), x3=rnorm(100))
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, df))
set.seed(1) 
training.samples <- df$x1%>%createDataPartition(p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train_df  <- df[training.samples, ]
test_df <- df[-training.samples, ]
train.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 2)
fit_train <-  train(Y ~ x1  + x2 + x3 , data = train_df, method = "gam", trControl = train.control)
Prediction_train <- as.numeric(predict(fit_train , data=train_df , type = "raw"))  
Prediction_test  <- as.numeric(predict(fit_train , newdata =test_df , type = "raw"))
```

Comment: I don't understand why the use of `ti` or `te` in the RHS of the formula would be any different incaret than in mgcv. The `caret` package mostly is a bundling of methoids imported from other packages and the "gam" method just uses the pkg:mgcv engine "under the hood". My suggestion (really more a demand of the SO community) is that you include library calls to create a MCVE if you wnat tested code or debugging efforts. Downvote for failing to offer MCVE.

Comment: Here's a "caret with gam" MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079519/validating-poisson-gam-models-with-caret

Comment: @IRTFM Thanks for the response. Question has been edited and codes are added. I know that the old version of caret package do not support ti function of gam, but I asked this question if any one know about the ti function in new version of caret. I could not find any thing yet.

Comment: I haven't the time to turn this tutorial section that shows how to craft a "custom model for regression" into a worked example, but I hope to come back to it in a few hours. Perhaps you or some other person will beat me to it. That would make me happy. https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html#Illustration3